# php - 404 Page Not Found codeigniter url

Tags: php, codeigniter

my framework is codeigniter and my site works fine.

example :

```
www.example.com/
```

now,I have copied all my codeigniter's folders to another dir like this:

```
www.example.com/test
```

now my urls:

```
www.example.com/profile //works fine
www.example.com/test/profile //not work
```

I get 404 page not found .

I changed base_url to :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/test';
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: Look for your `.htaccess` file, it'll be the `RewriteBase` condition in there I imagine

Comment: Do you still have all CodeIgniter files in your main directory.

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/test';` should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/test/';//notice ending slash`. Post `APPPATH . 'routes.php';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at your `.htaccess` file. Because it'll be in the `RewriteBase` condition in there. Check it and tell what You found.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does not support **multiple** subdirectory levels in your **controllers**

But still you can extend it.

You might have to extend **Router** Class

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have all CodeIgniter files in your main directory?

If yes, then you must remove them or you can create **SUBDOMAIN** to solve the issue.

> **Note**: Codeigniter don't support multiple subdirectory levels in your controllers.

If no, then you must look for your `.htaccess` file, it'll be the RewriteBase condition in there.